# Unit testing infinite Flux speed of generation

Tags: testing, project-reactor

I have Flux, which generates event in some pace (in infinite manner). I would like to use StepVerifier that after 5 seconds there is at least 2 events generated. How can I verify this behavior using StepVerifier?

Sample flux for testing can look like this:

```
public fluxTest() {
    final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);
    final Random rnd = new Random();

    final Flux<String> randomIntervalEmitter = Flux.generate(generator -> {
        try {
            final long counterDivided = counter.get() % 12;
            if (counterDivided > 0) {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(rnd.nextInt(1, 10));
            } else {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(rnd.nextInt(1, 50));
            }
            generator.next("asdf " + counterDivided);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    final Flux<String> regularDummyUpdate = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).map(e -> "" + (88 + (System.currentTimeMillis() % 104)));
    final Flux<String> stringFluxWithSomePace = randomIntervalEmitter.mergeWith(regularDummyUpdate);
    
    stringFluxWithSomePace.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in javadoc of StepVerifier:

> The verification must be triggered after the terminal expectations
> (completion, error, cancellation) have been declared, by calling one
> of the verify() methods.

So when I have infinite source, I need to trigger some **terminal operation**. **Complete** and **Error** is emitted from source (I am not changing it in any way for tests) and **Cancel** can be triggered by subscriber (StepVerifier). So **using thenCancel() and verify() on StepVerifier**, I can achieve to assert only on the beginning of the infinite stream.

```
    final var sv = StepVerifier.create(stringFluxWithSomePace.log())
            // in 23 seconds should at least some "heartbeat" come at least three times
            .expectSubscription()
            .expectNextCount(3)
            .thenCancel()
            .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(23));
```

Nice thing is, that after receiving any 3 items, stream is cancelled and test finished (in my case usually under a second).